Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output
I trying to update my react native app from Android API 33 to API 34. My emulator work fine but when I try to build .apk file my app crash at launch. When I create apk with:
gradle assembleRelease

Errors as below:
 - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-sensitive-info:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-sensitive-info:compileReleaseRenderscript' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-sensitive-info:compileReleaseShaders' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-sensitive-info:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-sensitive-info:extractReleaseAnnotations' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-sensitive-info:generateReleaseBuildConfig' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-sensitive-info:generateReleaseRFile' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-sensitive-info:generateReleaseResValues' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-sensitive-info:javaPreCompileRelease' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-sensitive-info:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-sensitive-info:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-sensitive-info:mergeReleaseJavaResource' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-sensitive-info:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-sensitive-info:mergeReleaseNativeLibs' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. 
Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-sensitive-info:mergeReleaseShaders' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-sensitive-info:packageReleaseAssets' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-sensitive-info:packageReleaseRenderscript' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-sensitive-info:packageReleaseResources' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-sensitive-info:parseReleaseLocalResources' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-sensitive-info:prepareLintJarForPublish' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-sensitive-info:prepareReleaseArtProfile' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-sensitive-info:processReleaseJavaRes' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-sensitive-info:processReleaseManifest' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. 
Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-sensitive-info:stripReleaseDebugSymbols' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-sensitive-info:syncReleaseLibJars' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-sensitive-info:writeReleaseAarMetadata' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-share:bundleReleaseLocalLintAar' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-share:compileReleaseAidl' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer 
to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-share:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-share:compileReleaseRenderscript' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-share:compileReleaseShaders' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-share:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-share:extractReleaseAnnotations' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-share:generateReleaseBuildConfig' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-share:generateReleaseRFile' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-share:generateReleaseResValues' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please 
refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-share:javaPreCompileRelease' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-share:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-share:mergeReleaseGeneratedProguardFiles' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: ''. Reason: Task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-share:mergeReleaseJavaResource' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please 
refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Execution optimizations have been disabled for 11 invalid unit(s) of work during this build to ensure correctness.
Please consult deprecation warnings for more details.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 20m 43s

The list is very long. Here are my configs:
android/build.gradle
buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
minSdkVersion = 22
compileSdkVersion = 34
targetSdkVersion = 34
ndkVersion = "22.0.7026061"
kotlinVersion = "1.6.21"

classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2")

gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-all.zip

I searched and found many people have met similar problems. But it seem there is no solution. Anyone can help?

connect logcat and check for error logged there when app crashes, there could an error which is not related to this gardle logs.

thanks, your comment make me noticed that it may not crash because of those logs, I tried to check some of my configs in package.json and it works without solve those gradle logs.
